# There are $8$ conjugates of $H$ in $G$, where $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup with $p=7$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $7$ in group $G:=PGL(2,7)$ (of order $336$). Show that there are $8$ conjugates of $H$ in $G$.

I know that $H$ is a Sylow $7$-subgroup so let $n_7$ denote the number of Sylow  $7$-subgroups in $G$. Since $n_7$ must be $1$ mod $7$ and must divide $48 = \frac{|G|}{7}$ then $n_7$ is either $1$ or $8$. 
I am not sure how to rule out $n_7 = 1$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like you could probably rule it out directly in this case by just writing down all 8 Sylow 7-subgroups - can you see how to do this?

Comment: But it is enough to write down two distinct  Sylow $7$-subgroups, which is easy - think upper and lower triangular matrices.

Comment: Is one of them the subgroup generated by diagonal matrices?